# ¿Cómo evito que el metodo .sort() mute el arreglo original en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-metodo

Tengo un array `lista` y quiero ordenarlo pero sin mutar ese array, así que cree otra variable `listaOrdenada` donde puse los datos del array `lista` y luego use el metodo .sort() para ordenarlo. El código a continuación:

```js
const lista = [950, 800, 812.5, 2000, 1000, 800, 850, 800, 525, 500, 725, 1625, 825, 4275, 1750, 1500, 2500, 2000, 3900, 3750]
;

const listaOdenada = lista;

lista.sort((a, b) => a - b);

console.log(lista)
```

El problema viene al querer usar el array original `lista` y ver que fue mutado. ¿Cómo evito que se mute el array original?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solo debes sacar una copia del array y ordenar la copia.

```js
const lista = [950, 800, 812.5, 2000, 1000, 800, 850, 800, 525, 500, 725, 1625, 825, 4275, 1750, 1500, 2500, 2000, 3900, 3750]
;

const listaOrdenada = [...lista]; //Sacas una copia de la lista

listaOrdenada.sort((a, b) => a - b); //Ordenas la copia

console.log(lista)  //Puedes ver que lista no ha mutado
console.log(listaOrdenada)  //Pero la copia si está mutada y ordenada
```

Answer (score 2):

Al igual de como aporto Pipe, clonar tu array **lista** pero con el metodo slice() de los Array Methods de JavaScript y luego lo ordenas.
Para mas informacion sobre **Array Methods**: [Metodo slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
 const lista = [950, 800, 812.5, 2000, 1000, 800, 850, 800, 525, 500, 725, 1625, 825, 4275, 1750, 1500, 2500, 2000, 3900, 3750]
    ;
    
    let listaOdenada = [] //Creas el nuevo array

    listaOdenada = lista.slice(); //Lo clonas
    //let listaOdenada = [] = listaOdenada = lista.slice(); Otra opción

    listaOdenada.sort((a, b) => a - b); //Ordenas el nuevo Array
    
    console.log(listaOdenada)
    console.log(lista)
```